# Duração do Notification

Tags: javascript, api

Estou utilizando a API da Notification, mas não estou achando uma forma de deixar a mensagem aberta direto, até ser clicada ou fechada pelo usuário. 
Percebi que o Google Hangouts faz isso, a notification fica lá até ser clicada.
Alguém ai tem alguma ideia?
Atualmente estou fazendo assim:

```
var detalhe = {
   body: msg,
   icon: 'icone.png',
};
notificacao = new Notification('Teste', detalhe);
```

Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Podes [edit] a pergunta e dar um exemplo com o código que tens a funcionar? tipo um jsFiddle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification) você deve usar como opção a propriedade `requireInteraction`, que vai receber um valor booleano.

```
var detalhe = {
    body: msg,
    icon: 'icone.png',
    requireInteraction: true
};
```

Isso deve te ajudar!